# How do I prevent a bash script from exiting?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, ngrok

I am trying to augment `ngrok http 80` by sending myself the random public address:

```
ngrok "$@" &

sendurl()

fg
```

Unfortunately, albeit ngrok screen comes back online, I get a prompt at the end of my bash script, like it terminated.

How do I keep ngrok running in the terminal "tab" as if I started it myself?

Comment: `sender(geturl())` is a syntax error. It's not really clear what you are referring to.

Comment: pseudocode for sending address

Comment: Psuedocode does not make a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but you can use a subshell and a minor sleep delay to get the desired functionality.

```bash
(sleep 5 && sendurl(geturl())) & # Customise delay to whatever feels best

ngrok "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the end of your script

```
while true
do
    echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
    sleep 1
done
```